# Problem with flyway on raspbian: Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: java, linux, raspbian, flyway

I am trying to run flyway on a raspberry pi without luck. I have downloaded and linked the program correctly but when I try to run it (migrate, -version, whatever) it fails with the error message `/usr/local/bin/flyway: line 72: /home/pi/flyway-6.3.1/jre/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. I have searched the web for a while now but haven't been able to find any case of a similar error. I'm guessing it has something to do with the system architecture, but am I screwed or is there some kind of a workaround?

```sh
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you run "file /home/pi/flyway-6.3.1/jre/bin/java"

Comment: @Johnb sorry for the late response, here is the output:
 
`jre/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=ac9d8ef7fb28223a1a1b6ce21c6139b165091dc7, not stripped`

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct about it being an architecture issue. The jre/bin/java file you have is complied for x86-64 (a modern Intel or AMD desktop/server processor), and your system is a armv71. So you will be unable to run the incorrect version of the JVM.

The next question is how was the incorrect jre installed on your machine. How did you install it? What do you mean "linked the program"?

To answer your broader question, are you screwed? Probably not. Java exist for the arm architectures. It becomes a question, of exactly which version of Java do you need, and setting it up correctly. It could take some time. You should create an [issue/feature request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues) for arm architecture support. (don't be surprised if they never do this) [this](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/d38670d2cbe9d58fbc1724a92be7fe996d0e0b8c/flyway-commandline/src/main/assembly/linux.xml#L31) is the line where they assume you will be using x86

I would recommend  virtual box, and Ubuntu for a data base migration tool. If you really need to run this tool in an embedded environment, I would be fascinated. Virtual box will allow you do set a x86-64 linux machine, and download with a graphical interface, then you can setup flyway on that.

Let us know what you plan to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To answer your questions, what I meant with "linking the program" was just creating a symlink for the binary file to make it runnable in the terminal. How did I install the wrong version of JRE? It's been a while since I did it so I don't really remember but I'm guessing I just used apt. Can't remember having any issues with the installation. I think I'll just use another tool for db migrations, it's a small project so installing a VM seems like overdoing it. Wouldn't it just be possible to change that line in linux.xml to point at my JRE though?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. I couldn't find any solution but at the end I tried crazy hack and worked like a charm.

1. Install `default-jdk` to raspberry
2. Delete `flyway/jre/bin/java` file
3. Re run `flyway`

Comment: how to delete flyway/jre/bin/java .. did you mean manually go the folder and delete it

Comment: @Kar Yes. Manually go to folder were flyway is located and delete java folder. I think something is wrong with default java which comes with flyway.